# Create subscription for change notifications on multiple resources

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

We have an application that creates a subscription on a calendar for changes.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
{
   "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
   "notificationUrl": "https://example.com/notifications",
   "resource": "users('room-01@example.com')/events",
   "expirationDateTime":"2020-11-14T14:56:29.000Z",
   "clientState": "Test"
}
```

This works as expected.
But now we are interested in calendar events for multiple rooms.
We want to subscribe our application to many calendars at once since we have many rooms (300+).
If we create separate subscriptions for each room we will likely hit the subscription limit of Microsoft.
We were hoping to subscribe for all resources that are member of a group:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
{
   "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
   "notificationUrl": "https://example.com/notifications",
   "resource": "groups('383efd01-29b6-4817-9a9c-8faf61a1e06a')/events",
   "expirationDateTime":"2020-11-14T14:56:29.000Z",
   "clientState": "Test"
}
```

This is not working...
Is there maybe another way to set the resource, wildcard?
Hope someone can help us or have a alternative approach, thanks in advance.

Comment: In order to avoid this throttling situation, i would have tried implementation subscribing to smaller size (say, 50 rooms), instead of 300+. The Microsoft Graph endpoint is normally highly performant. The infrastructure behind Microsoft 365 will allocate computing resources based on demand to ensure that periods of high traffic levels do not result in degraded performance. In addition to dynamic scaling of resources, another mechanism that Microsoft uses is throttling. If you make too many requests then you will start to get HTTP 429 (too many requests) response codes returned.

Comment: For more info you can refer Microsoft Guidance @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling

Comment: In the same lines, you may want to consider Microsoft Graph Data Connect and see if it fits your scenario. If yes, then you can understand that it allows you to get at the same data that's available through Microsoft Graph APIs (currently only a limited subset is available), but in a scalable way.- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/data-connect-concept-overview

Comment: @Dev Thanks for your comments. Do I understand you correct that I can subscribe to many room (300+) but it has to be done not to many at once or too fast to avoid throttling?

Comment: Yes, you can give a try with Microsoft Graph Data connect to see if it helps. Also check out the scenario's that suits you.

Comment: I will move this to answer. So it can be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 0):

- In order to avoid this throttling situation, i would have tried implementation subscribing to smaller size (say, 50 rooms), instead of 300+. The Microsoft Graph endpoint is normally highly performant. The infrastructure behind Microsoft 365 will allocate computing resources based on demand to ensure that periods of high traffic levels do not result in degraded performance. In addition to dynamic scaling of resources, another mechanism that Microsoft uses is throttling. If you make too many requests then you will start to get HTTP 429 (too many requests) response codes returned. Here is [the throttling guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling).
- In the same lines, you may want to consider [Microsoft Graph Data Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/data-connect-concept-overview) and see if it fits your scenario. If yes, then you can understand that it allows you to get at the same data that's available through Microsoft Graph APIs (currently only a limited subset is available), but in a scalable way.